# Best solution for storing JSON data in iPhone

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am working on developing a civic engagement app that provides information on bills making their way through a particular state house. The API I am using updates every hour, if a user accesses the information within that hour, I would like to archive the most recent JSON data on their phone (and update it on the hour as well). What is the best solution for storing JSON data? Core Data, NSCoding, or UserDefaults

Comment: put it into the app's _Documents/_ folder after you archived it (via `NSCoding`), I __would not__ recommend to use core-data it is pointless to use for such primitive file storing; user-defaults is not for storing files either.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data will be the best option to cache your data locally. UserDefaults is least recommendable as if any particular value, corresponding to the key you are trying to save, comes Nil, Your application will crash.

Comment: Your reason for not using UserDefaults is wrong. The reason not to use UserDefaults is because you should not store app data in UserDefaults. It's trivial to properly handle a value not existing in UserDefaults without the application crashing.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to save Serialization data as plist file:

```
let plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: jsonDict, format: .xml, options: PropertyListSerialization.WriteOptions(0))
try plistData.write(to: urlToLocalFile, options: .atomic)
```

And then read this file:

```
if let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOf: urlToLocalFile) {
   //do something with dictionary
}
```